# How to Add progress bar in each list section in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, datetimepicker, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

hey guys I get very upset from this and now I need your help please
I want to add progress bar in list view using flutter I have tried many things but I really don't get it. so please help me with this. and the other thing I want to know that how I make my progress bar working with time and date I mean to say that I get time and date like Microsoft project and I want to show progress according to time and date. soooo please help me guys...

Comment: Please add some code snippet what you have done yet so dar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class LoaderList extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoaderList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          height: 100,
          child: Center(
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              // add value to control the progress
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```